# In ASP.NET can I change the values of some fields from a DB bound to a grid in the binding process?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I have the following code behind:

```
List<Articles> articles = (from em in db.Articles orderby em.ReceivedDate descending select em).ToList();
gvArticles.DataSource = articles;
gvArticles.DataBind();
```

Where gvArticles is a GridView.  The following is the asp code within that grid:

```
<p style='font-weight:bold;font-size:17px;color:black;'> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("datePrinted").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>  
</p> 
<asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server"  Text= '<%#Eval("Content")%>'></asp:Label>
```

... that will clearly show from the DB the fields 'datePrinted' and 'Content'

Is there any way that I can show other value in 'datePrinted' based on a condition?  For example, if 'datePrinted' is before 1/1/1990 then put "N/A" instead of the field 'datePrinted' itself?

Or a bit more complex, put "-" if the day is the same as the previous record (time can be different, just day/month/year is the same)?

Of course I could calculate all of that and store it in the DB, so I will pull other fields from the DB, but that sounds extremely inefficient, for any future condition create a new field in the DB.  So are there any other ways to achieve the same results?

Ideally a condition, formula, or function that translates values from the DB before binding them to the grid is the most desirable solution.

Any idea?

Comment: all you need is a switch statement

Comment: Bender, how? where? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your code behind. Call that method parsing your value instead of using eval.

E.g

```
  public static string ConvertDate(DateTime date)
  {

        if (date < new DateTime(1990, 1,1) )
        {
            return "N/A";
        }
        else
        {

            return date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }

  }
```

Place this method where you placed your Eval("datePrinted").

```css
<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# ConvertDate(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("datePrinted")) ) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is another way to solve it, I would assume that some global variables to implement some sort of persistence between calls will be required, but it is doable. Do you mind putting the proper ASP code to have this properly documented?

Comment: BTW, you may have realized that I just found out that you can also process the list prior to bind it to the grid data source, but I like your solution better. :)

Comment: Sure you can access it. Which ever way you prefer is ok. If it's something you need on other pages of your app. You can create a partial class for your Articles class and create another property that will deal with what you want displayed

Answer (score 0):

After days trying to figure out what to do, I found one answer just after posting this question.  Basically I realized that you can process the List before assign it to the binding.  So my second sample, I did this after loading the list and before assign it to the grid datasource:

```
    string   prevDate = "";
    foreach(Article myArticle in articles) {
       if (((DateTime)myArticle.ReceivedDate).ToShortDateString() != prevDate) {
           prevDate = ((DateTime)myMail.ReceivedDate).ToShortDateString();
           myArticle.ReceivedDate = prevDate;
       }
       else myArticle.ReceivedDate = "-";
   }
```

Now, I am not a LINQ expert, if anyone can do the same code in the line where the DB is loaded in the List, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Don't expect someone to answer a question that you've posted in an answer. If you'd really like an answer, you can ask a follow-up question.